# Adding style code to html tag in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is there anyway I can display a div correctly with style code in the tag. For example I was wanting to have a div banner but Wordpress does not display the background color but it does show the text is there any way I can change it.

Example of what I was wanting todo.

```
<div id="Break" style="color:blue">
Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use background-color instead of color.

```html
<div id="Break" style="background-color:blue">
Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be adding styles in your html either, this should be;

index.php (or wherever you want to use it)

```
<div id="Break">
Test
</div>
```

style.css

```
#break{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Achieves exactly the same but is a much better way of doing it.